# Unicode character ′ (U+2032) not set up for use with LaTeX. ---- bibliography issue

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio, texworks

I'm stuck with an issue that drives me mad.

I get the error "Unicode character ′ (U+2032) not set up for use with LaTeX." when I try to compile my file. The line marked for the error is "\printbibliography".

I know LaTeX doesn't like Unicode so I checked the whole document for " ' " (which always compiled well before) and replaced it with "\textquotesingle" but that didn't help.
My next step was to remove all ' from my bibliography, that also didn't help.
I'm at a loss for solutions since the bibliography always used to compile well and I only added a few new sources since the last time. To exclude them, I removed them and compiled again but that also didn't help.

Any hints in the right direction are appreciated! I'm using TeXworks and TeXstudio with the following combination to load my bib:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

....

\printbibliography
```

Comment: Use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2032}{HEREHEREHERE}`  to find out where it is. (And if the char is correct in your bib, then you can give it a sensible declaration with this command, LaTeX has no problems with unicode, it only doesn't predeclare all (many tenthousands) code points.) (And better use biber instead of bibtex, it handles unicode input better).

Comment: "remove all ' from my bibliography,"  removing `'` (U+0027) is not going to affect the occurrences of `′` (U+2032)

Comment: "The line marked for the error is "\printbibliography"." the actual error message in the log will show the line in the bbl file with the character.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks a lot, that helped!